# Golang - GORM: sql: Scan error on column index 0, name "row": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type string into type *models.User;

Tags: go, go-gorm

## Background

The requirement is to use GORM for inserting rows into PostgreSQL but only using raw query.

My codes are as follow:

```golang
const userModelFieldsCreateReturn := "id, uuid, slug, username"
```

```golang
// User Model
func (repo *Repository) CreateUsers(ctx *context.Context, users []*models.User) ([]*models.User, error) {
    var returnedUsers []*models.User
    inserts := []string{}

    for _, user := range users {
        // Optional Fields
        tierIDString := "NULL" // Default
        if user.TierID.Valid {
            tierIDString = "'" + strconv.FormatInt(user.TierID.Int64, 10) + "'"
        }
        statusString := "inactive" // Default
        if user.Status != nil {
            statusString = string(*user.Status)
        }

        inserts = append(inserts, "('"+user.Slug+"', "+"'"+user.Username+"', "+"'"+user.Email+"', "+"'"+user.Password+"', "+"'"+user.Key+"', "+tierIDString+", "+"'"+statusString+"')")
    }

    query := fmt.Sprintf(
        constants.CreateQuery,
        constants.UsersModel,
        userModelFieldsCreate,
        strings.TrimSuffix(strings.Join(inserts, ", "), ", "),
        userModelFieldsCreateReturn,
    )

    // Debug
    fmt.Println("==========")
    fmt.Println(query)
    fmt.Println("==========")

    // Debug
    var scannedUsers []interface{}
    // results := repo.DBPostgres.Raw(query).Scan(&scannedUsers)

    results := repo.DBPostgres.Raw(query).Scan(&returnedUsers)
    if results.Error != nil {
        results.Assign()
        return nil, results.Error
    }

    // Debug
    // for _, scannedUser := range scannedUsers {
    //  // var user *models.User
    //  user := &models.User{}
    //  byte, _ := json.Marshal(scannedUser)
    //  _ = json.Unmarshal(byte, user)
    // }

    // Debug
    fmt.Println("=====")
    fmt.Println(scannedUsers)
    fmt.Println(returnedUsers)
    fmt.Println("=====")

    // Debug
    // return users, nil

    return returnedUsers, nil
}
```

Here is the model:

```golang
package models

import (
    coreConstants "core/constants"
    "database/sql"
    "database/sql/driver"
    "time"

    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type UserStatus string

const (
    Active   UserStatus = coreConstants.Active
    Inactive UserStatus = coreConstants.Inactive
)

func (us *UserStatus) Scan(value string) error {
    *us = UserStatus([]byte(value))

    return nil
}

func (us UserStatus) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return string(us), nil
}

type User struct {
    ID       uint   `gorm:"primarykey"`
    UUID     string `gorm:"not null;default:md5(random()::text || clock_timestamp()::text)::uuid"`
    Slug     string `gorm:"not null"`
    Username string `gorm:"not null"`

    Email    string `gorm:"not null"`
    Password string `gorm:"not null"`
    Key      string
    TierID   sql.NullInt64 // Optional
    Tier     *Tier
    Status   *UserStatus `gorm:"not null;default:'inactive'" sql:"type:user_status"` // Have Default

    CreatedAt time.Time      `gorm:"not null;default:current_timestamp"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time      `gorm:"not null;default:current_timestamp"`
    DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index"`
}
```

The query is as follows (I have tried to execute this query into the database and it ran as expected):

```
INSERT INTO users (
        slug, username, email, password, key, tier_id, status
)
VALUES
        ('notalentgeek', 'notalentgeek', 'notalentgeek@gmail.com', '$2a$08$B/.rN7cCv4Ii7VHjl1ZppObUfZeCfae2vPvi4PH1siIp4/JOWNo/u', 'b7a1bd7ca3eb87b80685e5957d676609', NULL, 'inactive'), ('notalentgeek', 'notalentgeek', 'mikael.pratama@yahoo.com', '$2a$08$vrK1Dh9RgqJusoyLPxDLuez8/RZEjZNvyBgImw34QXu3VaN6Ht36m', '7802676f557266524253d04e17ef36aa', NULL, 'inactive')
RETURNING (id, uuid, slug, username);
```

## Error

**Error happened at line `results := repo.DBPostgres.Raw(query).Scan(&returnedUsers)` :**

```
sql: Scan error on column index 0, name "row": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type string into type *models.User;
```

It seems that the `RETURNING` values from the `query` can't be scanned into `[]*models.User` .

I can use `[]interface{}` :

```golang
// Debug
var scannedUsers []interface{}
results := repo.DBPostgres.Raw(query).Scan(&scannedUsers)
```

Instead of using `[]*models.User` :

```golang
var returnedUsers []*models.User
results := repo.DBPostgres.Raw(query).Scan(&returnedUsers)
```

And:

```golang
fmt.Println(scannedUsers)
```

Will return:

```
[(3,2320a7e6-d675-bb19-bd8c-84af1c381b39,notalentgeek,notalentgeek) (4,6b69d37c-e17c-1ce1-d47f-ffe3a3e09a8f,notalentgeek,notalentgeek)]
```

No error, but not a type I want.

## Edits

- In the query I tried to create multiple Users at once to the database.
- If I change `RETURNING (id, uuid, slug, username)` into `RETURNING (id)` (just `RETURNING` a value) the error doesn't happen and the request succeed.